# Drag and drop in listView: drop over a listItem so as to combine them rather than sorting

Tags: android, android-listview, drag-and-drop

I want an expandable list in which I can drag a child item and drop it over some other parent list item which will result in child moving from one parent to other. I only need a direction how we can achieve this in general listview (let alone exapandable). Examples are available for picking up a listitem to change the order of listview i.e. to sort that list. How can I accomplish dropping over a view in order to group them.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet will be putting your effort on customizing and making your own listview, Consider extending `AdapterView`, this will give you more power over controlling child display and organizations, Putting animation such and drag and drop will be easier for you in this case, Otherwise with simple list view it might work but i doubt if it would generate the required result you want.

Here is a link for exending AdapterView and customizations, go through it it will give you enough confidance to put in your animation. I tried almost similar stuff and was succesfull by same way, unfortunately I dont have implemented code with me.

http://developer.sonymobile.com/2010/05/20/android-tutorial-making-your-own-3d-list-part-1/

Else with list view try doing following,

Your listview should be wrapped inside a framelayout, you will need layers

1. Enable drawing cache for childrens, coz animation you seek requires playing with bitmaps
2. Second, when you touch a child in listview, get the bitmap of child, and inflate it at same coordinates of touched child, you can get position of Child easily.
3. Now time for some animation, you enable drag and drop over inflated bitmap, now when you move it, first thing you need to do is, shifting all the childrens in list view either Up or Down depending upon movement of finger, you can define somekind of threshold like unless half the height of children is moved you wont shift childs in listview up or down.
4. Moving child will be easy, all you need to do is applying Transformation animation to all the currently visible child in listview, use childCount and ChildAt api for the same, and animation set for playing them together.
5. Thats it when you build space by shifting child, user will feel like drag drop and shift, all the thing you need, when user places it a place, just modify your dataset underneath listview reposition it based on recent changes by user and refresh it,so that listview reorders itself.